# How to find Location using Zipcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, geolocation, zipcode

I am new iphone developer,please help to me.how can i find particular shops list in particular Zip Code.. that means i need to place pins in Some shops by searching Zipcode

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a definitive "Right Way" to do what you're asking, but if it were me...

I would probably use Google's [Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) to get a list of so-called Places (I gather this includes a fairly comprehensive list of businesses, as well as other points of interest) near the user. The API requires lat/long coordinates to resolve the list, you could either get that data from the user's iOS device (I don't develop for this platform so I can't give specifics) using Apple's location API, or if you really want to do a lookup by zipcode you might want to look at Google's [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Keep in mind that Google's services are by no means the only game in town, and there are certainly other ways to do what you ask. But if it was me, this seems like the simplest solution